# How to convert variables/values into a spreadsheet/table on PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PS script that will look at all the sub-folders in a directory, get the lastWrite time,size and the parent folder name of the newest file in the folder and convert the values into a human-readable format such as a CSV, HTML table etc.

So far, I was able to gather all the values I wanted with the following script. I now need to make it look good and send it as a report on a daily basis (I know the mail function, so you can skip it).

```
$dir = "\\some\directory"
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Directory 
Foreach ($i in $folders.fullname)
{
 $newestfile = Get-ChildItem -Path $i | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 
  $parentPath = (Split-Path $newestfile.FullName).Trim("\\some\directory")
 $size = [math]::truncate($newestfile.length / 1MB)
 $parentPath + " " + [string]$size + " MB " + $newestfile.LastWriteTime
}
```

This may not be the most efficient script so far, but it returns what I need quite fast, but I'm of course open to improvements if you have one.

As a result, I get a bunch of results like this:

XXXX 846 MB March-04-15 2:35:51 AM

I'd like to convert this into an easily human-readable format, sorted by date.

Does anyone know a function on how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Focus on asking one question. If it isn't broken, SO isn't the site for it, Code Review exists for that. As a matter of netiquette, avoid making it look like you want someone do do your job for you. (I.e. this isn't a good place to post specifications and expect people to write a working app or script for you)

Comment: Matthew, 

As you can see, I've made an effort to create most of the script on my own and I wasn't able to figure out one aspect of the script. I'm not asking to do the whole thing. An answer such as "look at Create-Table" function, it does what you want to do" would be enough for me. Your comment doesn't make sense. I don't need a lecture on netiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means a finished product, but an example of how you might want to create a custom object to help control the output.

```
#$dir = "\\some\directory"
$GetFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse

foreach ($a in $GetFiles){

$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileName -Value  $a.Name
Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastAccess - Value $a.LastAccessTime
Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Directory -Value  $a.Directory
Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Size -Value  ((Get-Item $a.FullName).Length / 1MB)
$obj | Export-Csv -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\output.csv" -Append - NoTypeInformation
}

Import-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\output.csv" | Sort-Object LastAccess - `enter code here`Descending | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Great, this is very close to what I want. Thanks for the help.